# Suddenly connection via wpa_supplicant fails without obvious reason

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, wpa-supplicant, wpa2

Straight forward wifi client to infra AP connectivity by using wpa_supplicant (network-manager is not installed)

```
wpa_cli -iwlan0 add_network
1
wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 1 ssid '"myssid"'
OK
wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 1 psk '"mypwd"'
OK
wpa_cli -iwlan0 enable_network 1
```

As result "Association request to the driver failed"
in syslog strange entries

> nl80211: MLME connect failed: ret=-1 (Operation not permitted)
>
> wlan0: Association request to the driver failed

SSID and PSK are correct obviously. Tearing my hairs out - what is the problem?
The same problem with any other ssid.

dmesg output

> brcmfmac: brcmf_c_set_joinpref_default: Set join_pref error (-1)
> brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_connect: BRCMF_C_SET_SSID failed (-1)

Ideas? Direction? Where to look?

Comment: There is a reason we use NetworkManager. This is it! Ordinarily I would focus on the wifi device, the firmware, and the SSID config. If you use NetworkManager, it generally handles the rest, but now there are lots of questions. Can we see output from /sbin/ifconfig? And does your router allow other devices, such as cell phones to attach? Finally, does same computer work on other routers, in other places?

Comment: ifconfig shows wlan0 correctly - no issues here.
router is ok . moreover, the same computer used to connect to this very router previously.
Not sure what changed, but now it just not works. maybe some os upgrade or some configuration.
i can rollback to the original image and it works. but not configured one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is solved**

It is related to interesting side effect of driver initialization optimization. I have one physical wireless adapter with two virtual interfaces: client (managed) and hotspot (access point). The correct order of load is AP and then Managed (this is another issue, not sure where it comes from). When both interfaces are brought up at the same time or close enough one to another, later interface tries to reuse already loaded instance of device driver, which is obviously impossible (and this is where "Operation not permitted" comes from), so wpa_supplicant is not being initialized properly.

The solution is make AP to be loaded automatically at early stage, while leave Managed to manual mode. Then modify rc.local (or any other late running trigger) to enable Managed interface. For me (sleep 20 || sudo ifup wlan1) & works perfectly, so problem is solved.

Having said that, i think that it is required to open ticket for Debian to fix this issue, since, it is clearly OS bug.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day, I was in this exact situation!